# What's the rationale for using -start and -end directives in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, directive

In order to allow repeating multiple elements, such as `dd` and `dt` in a definition list, [angularjs will support start and end directives](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/e46100f7097d9a8f174bdb9e15d4c6098395c3f2). But what's the rationale for using this, instead of an element directive? Wouldn't it make more sense to be able to do something like

```
<dl>
    <ng-repeat for="element in collection">
        <dt>element.name</dt>
        <dd>element.description</dd>
    </ng-repeat>
</dl>
```

The directive would remove the ng-repeat element and replace add the repeated elements in its place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that that is the eventual goal, but that there were technical reasons why this wasn't compatible with the current angular and perhaps the current set of browsers they want to support.

Go to this page:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1891

And search for "Syntax X"